# How to load ELF image to memory and execute?

Tags: c, linux, memory, executable, elf

I've been trying to figure this out for days. Clearly, I'm too inexperienced to understand the actual code from various examples, and no matter how hard I try, I cannot find an explanation simple enough to follow. This is really not my cup of tea.

My question is, could I get a link (or answer) that has some very easy-to-understand pseudo-code or explanation of how to do the following:

In a c program, load another ELF executable into memory, set up memory and stack and all other necessary variables, and then execute it.

I understand the basic concepts, but it's just not coming together for me. I've checked many other sources, including here on StackOverflow, and they're all too complicated for my idiot brain to understand.

Thank you.

Comment: See my answer to the possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417930/379897 and note that doing this would only make sense if you're writing an operating system. For normal usage, you "load an elf image" via the `execve` function (or another exec-family function.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do it at the user level.  Obviously, the kernel does it, and the `ld.so.1` dynamic loader gets involved too.  But simulating either of those is not trivial.

Comment: @R.. I saw that post but it doesn't really make sense to me. I know you have to load something to memory, but that's as far as I understand it at all. That answer is too detailed on one specific issue; I'm not quite that far in understanding yet.

Comment: @Sefu: what are you really trying to do? Specifically? Do you really want to simulate an operating system's executor? Or do you just want to run a program?

Comment: @rici I am trying to write a program that given an executable (elf), runs that given executable in user space. As far as I understand, that means copying the binary code, setting up a stack, and passing control to the new program. I just don't have a clue on how to implement this.

Comment: @sefu: the operating system will do all that stuff for you. If you don't need to hang around while the program runs, use `exec` or one of its variants (there are six). If you need to wait for the program to finish, use `fork`, `exec` and `wait`.

Comment: @rici I know about those, but the purpose of this exercise is to learn how it works under the hood. `execve` is essentially what I'm trying to replace.

Comment: @sefu: in that case, I have no idea what's out of bounds. You can use dlopen to load an object file and dlsym to find its `main` symbol; you can use getcontext and makecontext to set up a stack, and setcontext to switch to it. (The *context functions are deprecated; the non-deprecated way of doing it is with a thread, which would be even easier.) Is that what you're looking for, or are you supposed to write a loader?

Comment: @Sefu: In order to duplicate what the kernel does in userspace, you would need to start out with a program which occupies a separate part of address space from what the target program occupies. This is impossible to guarantee at runtime without writing at least part of the program in asm so that it can relocate itself at runtime. (The kernel avoids this by using a disjoint virtual address range from what userspace uses.) Then, you would just `mmap` the main program at the load addresses specified in its program headers, and if it's dynamic linked, do the same for the dynamic linker...

Comment: ...then, you would setup environment pointers, an ELF aux vector, arguments, etc. at the stop of the stack address range, load the right register values, and jump to the entry point of the dynamic linker or main program (depending on if it's dynamic linked).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux x86 execve is syscall number 11, which can be called with:

```
long execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]){
  long r;
  asm volatile("int $128" : "=a"(r):"a"(11),"b"(filename),"c"(argv),"d"(envp):"memory");
  return r;
}
```

Which is how most libc will implement it (more indirectly though with error handling etc...)

To see how the execve syscall works, check out the linux kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

> In a c program, load another ELF executable into memory, set up memory and stack and all other necessary variables, and then execute it.

You can't really do this in a C program, because the C program is already loaded into memory (from its own ELF image) and running.  The two ELF images are going to conflict with each other, so when you try to map the new image, you'll screw up the old (running) image part way through and things will not work.

The first thing the kernel does when exec'ing an image is that it clears out (empties) the user address space, so the new image can be loaded without any conflicts.

Now that said, you CAN (with careful linking scripts) arrange to build two ELF images with no conflicts, so that the first one can load the second one and both can exist in memory at the same time.  That's essentially the way that ld.so (the dynamic linker) works -- it's linked at special addresses so it can coexist with 'normal' programs.  But any two 'normal' ELF executables are going to want to live at the same address(es)

Comment: In theory, could't he for example, does the basic kernel's job to load the ELF file (ie, the executable program) at kernel's executable runnable address and it just run or by no means it could work?

Comment: this is not true. How does UPX do that, then? go check it's source.