# Reading the program header contents of an ELF file

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, elf

How is it possible to extract loadable program headers individually from ELF files? 
By examining a binary using readelf one can get output similar to:

```
$ readelf -l helloworld

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400440
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000000070c 0x000000000000070c  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                 0x0000000000000230 0x0000000000000238  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000e28 0x0000000000600e28 0x0000000000600e28
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000000005e4 0x00000000004005e4 0x00000000004005e4
                 0x0000000000000034 0x0000000000000034  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417312/which-part-of-elf-file-must-be-loaded-into-the-memory) question answers how loadable headers are being mapped to memory(and where) but does not specify from where(from which offset and size) are the sections read within the given binary.
Is it determined by the current program header's fields **p_offset** and **p_filesz**?

Comment: Why not inspect `readelf`'s sources?

Comment: Suggest adding `ELF` tag.

Comment: @alk The source is quite lengthy and could have been commented more.

Comment: There's nothing from nothing ... especially if it for free! ;-)

Comment: any example of it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Proghdr {
        uint32_t p_type;
        uint32_t p_offset;
        uint32_t p_va;
        uint32_t p_pa;
        uint32_t p_filesz;
        uint32_t p_memsz;
        uint32_t p_flags; 
        uint32_t p_align;
};


struct Elf *elf_header = ...
struct Proghdr *ph;
if (elf_header->e_magic != ELF_MAGIC)
    goto bad;
ph = (struct Proghdr *) ((uint8_t *) elf_header + elf_header->e_phoff);
eph = ph + ELFHDR->e_phnum;
for (; ph < eph; ph++)
    if(ph->p_type == PT_LOAD)
        /*read_pload (dst address in memory, how many bytes to read, offset in the file) */
        read_pload(ph->p_pa, ph->p_memsz, ph->p_offset);
```

Comment: @Employed Russian explain

Comment: `read` takes 3 parameters: file descriptor, buffer to read into, and length. You are giving it: physical address, memory size, file offset. None make any sense.

Comment: Don't you think that's an *important* detail? Also, naming your own function `read` with non-standard signature is a really bad idea(TM).

Comment: Sure. It's 32-bit only code, and it answers the question with 20 lines of code where a simple "yes" would suffice, but it's fine otherwise.

Comment: There are two questions. The first one was "How is it possible to extract loadable program headers individually from ELF files?" I answered both. Anyway thanks for the assist and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it determined by the current program header's fields p_offset and p_filesz?

Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

get program header table address by reading `e_phoff`, header count (number of headers) by reading `e_phnum` and size of each header by reading `e_phentsize` from elf file header. the trick is that each header is of same size of `e_phentsize`. So after every `e_phentsize`, new header starts and headers for total `e_phnum`